# python update cursor issue - error with %s symbol?

Tags: python

this is probably a *really* stupid problem, but i've been looking at it for a few hours and cannot work it out.

So here goes:

```
 def updateEntryAsYoutubeProcessing(self,conn,id):
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            try:
                    numberAffected = cursor.execute("update new_files set is_youtube = 1 where id=%s",(id))
                    conn.commit()
            except MySQLdb.IntegrityError,e:
                    logging.warn("update failed with error \n\t%d:%s",e.args[0],e.args[1])
                    raise
            finally:
                    cursor.close()
```

this code *always* results in an error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mydaemon.py", line 28, in loopForEachFileInDirectory
    self.updateEntryAsYoutubeProcessing(conn,id)
  File "mydaemon.py", line 80, in updateEntryAsYoutubeProcessing
    numberAffected = cursor.execute("update new_files set is_youtube = 1 where id=%s",(id))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
  ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1")
```

I've tried my code with double quotes, triple double quotes, the sql defined as a variable and placed in the execute, everything i can think of.

What am i missing?

I've tried the sql on the database, and it works fine (substituting the %s with a value, obvi).

EDIT:
ok, so the problem i was *really* having was that id was None. The next problem i was having was that, as noted in the answers (thanks!), I needed to make the `(id)` into `(id,)`, because tuples.

Now that it is a tuple, I get a "Nonetype" error thrown. Thanks all, obviously i'm fixing my code to use typles (and also to not inject None into the db)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments must be a sequence and (id) is not a tuple, but (id,) is. Try this:

```
cursor.execute("update new_files set is_youtube = 1 where id=%s",(id,))
```

Comment: You know what is weird? When one minute you have 4 answers, you go and test one of them, come back, and almost *all* the answers have gone, the person with the right answer has gone, and someone else has replaced him - with an equally right answer. I'm baffled, you're correct, and now it is time for dinner

Answer (score 1):

Try passing it in as an array as shown here in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

```
cursor.execute("update new_files set is_youtube = 1 where id=%s", [id])
```

EDIT: Below is an example of what NOT to do because of SQL injection vulnerabilities - see comment below

You need a `%` rather than `,` in your string format:

```
# NOT SAFE
"update new_files set is_youtube = 1 where id=%s" % id
```

Comment: -1, Not using parameterized queries is a good way to get SQL injection vulnerabilities. Python's DBAPI supports passing the parameters as separate arguments to prevent this.

Comment: @interjay Sorry, that is absolutely correct. I have left the post up but edited it so others will not make the same mistake.

Comment: +1 because you kept it up with an explanation, and i never knew why i was using the comma

Answer (score 1):

the squence type is (variable,) so  you have this type error message;

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lock.py", line 16, in 
    cur.callproc("ldap_lock", {tckimlik} )
TypeError: arguments must be a sequence

try

cursor.callproc("sp_name", (id,))